# Solr Cloud: Seeing many errors in logging without ill effects. Should I be worried?

Tags: java, solr, cloud

```
8/24/2021, 4:42:25 PM
```

ERROR true
x:questions_shard7_replica_n80
ErrorReportingConcurrentUpdateSolrClient
Error when calling SolrCmdDistributor$Req: cmd=add{,​id=q36445451}; node=ForwardNode: http://localhost:8983/solr/questions_shard6_replica_n70/ to http://localhost:8983/solr/questions_shard6_replica_n70/
java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.DeferredContentProvider.flush(DeferredContentProvider.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.OutputStreamContentProvider$DeferredOutputStream.flush(OutputStreamContentProvider.java:151)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.OutputStreamContentProvider$DeferredOutputStream.write(OutputStreamContentProvider.java:145)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.FastOutputStream.flush(FastOutputStream.java:216)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.FastOutputStream.flushBuffer(FastOutputStream.java:209)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.marshal(JavaBinCodec.java:172)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.marshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:106)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BinaryRequestWriter.write(BinaryRequestWriter.java:83)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.send(Http2SolrClient.java:342)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateHttp2SolrClient$Runner.sendUpdateStream(ConcurrentUpdateHttp2SolrClient.java:237)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateHttp2SolrClient$Runner.run(ConcurrentUpdateHttp2SolrClient.java:181)
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.DeferredContentProvider.flush(DeferredContentProvider.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.OutputStreamContentProvider$DeferredOutputStream.flush(OutputStreamContentProvider.java:151)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.OutputStreamContentProvider$DeferredOutputStream.write(OutputStreamContentProvider.java:145)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.FastOutputStream.flush(FastOutputStream.java:216)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.FastOutputStream.flushBuffer(FastOutputStream.java:209)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.close(JavaBinCodec.java:1277)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.marshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:107)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:774)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:120)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client.connect(HTTP2Client.java:397)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.http.HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.connect(HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.http.HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.connect(HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient$1.connect(HttpClient.java:620)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient$1.succeeded(HttpClient.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient$1.succeeded(HttpClient.java:590)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SocketAddressResolver$Async.lambda$resolve$1(SocketAddressResolver.java:186)
... 4 more
Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]

Comment: Running latest version of solr 8. With Solr 6 didn't have these errors, after upgrade. But cluster is healthy and runs fine. 
How to prevent these, or ignore them?

Comment: `node=ForwardNode: http://localhost:8983/solr/questions_shard6_replica_n70/ to http://localhost:8983/solr/questions_shard6_replica_n70/ java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` seems to be quite the clue... there's something to do with a replica that it can't connect to... maybe enable or disable that feature?

Comment: That's a good point. But how can I disable the feature? All replicas need to talk to each other, it's not optional I don't think...